# System of equations premutations

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

When I permutate a,b,c,d,e to the left the value on the right side changes by 1. Can I make some use of this information to solve the following system of equations?
I don't really know have to solve it though.
$$a + 2b+3c + 4d + 5e =5$$
$$2a+3b+4c+5d+1e =4$$
$$3a+4b+5c+1d+2e =3$$
$$4a+5b+c+2d+3e =2$$
$$5a+b+2c+3d+4e =1$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  If you add all the equations you get $a+b+c+d+e=1$.  If you subtract the first from the second.....